# How to change the default face of Org mode to different font from the default face of Emac?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Like the title, the face of the normal text portion is default, how can I change the font of that face but only apply to Org-mode.

I also find a face name: org-default, but when I try to change the font of that face using:

```
(set-face-attribute 'org-default nil :font "Fira Mono" :height 130)
```

Emac output an error said that face is invalid.

I have tried using this code from another question from the emac sub:

```
(defun my/org-mode-font-configuartion ()
  (face-remap-add-relative 'default :font "Fira Mono" :height 130))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'my/org-mode-font-configuartion)
```

But when I use M-x describe-face, the text portion still hasn't changed. Any help would be appreciated.

What I would expect is the default face in Org mode has different font than the default face in Emac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix my problem thanks to **Protesilaos Stavrou**, you can find more [here](https://protesilaos.com/codelog/2022-01-08-emacs-face-remap-add-relative/).

```
;Function only run in Org mode, to separate it with emac.
(defface your-new-face-remap
    '((t (:font "Fira Mono" :height 130)))
    "My custom font for org mode default.")

(define-minor-mode your-new-face-mode
    "Remap the face of org mode default."
    :local t
    :init-value nil
    (if your-new-face-mode
        ;if true do
        (setq your-new-face-remap-cookie
            (face-remap-add-relative 'default 'your-new-face-remap-style))
        ;if false do
        (face-remap-remove-relative my-comment-remap-cookie)))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'your-new-face-mode)
```

The defface is really finicky, you must have '((' for it to work.